# angular 2 data between dialog and component

Tags: angular

In my project I have list of objects. I want when I click on one of them dialog box to be open with the information about the object. Also if I edit the object changes to be saved. My question is how to pass data from component to dialog and reverse?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: it would be help to add some code showing your attempt at solving this problem, even if it is not correct.

Comment: Please show evidence of the research carried out, the code you have implemented and the exact issue you are experiencing - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: To pass data between the component and the dialog For example this https://plnkr.co/edit/GmOUPtXYpzaY81qJjbHp?p=preview